# Pass a multiple arguments from a child props to the parent method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react js . Here, what I am trying to do is that , I have a parent component which is like:

```
onchange(event) {
        console.log("function will be callled", event.target.value, event.target.id);


     { (this.props.lowData) && this.props.lowData.Low.length > 0 && this.props.lowData.Low.map(data => (
                        <LowRow technologies={this.state.technologies} onChange={this.onchange.bind(this)} data={data} key={data.id} />
                    ))}
```

Here there is a `onchnage` method I am passing as a props to the child element, which is:

```
<select className="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start selectId techDrop  margin-left-10" onChange={props.onChange}>
                    <option disabled selected value>None Selected</option>
                    {props.technologies && <Select techData={props.technologies} options={props.technologyName} />}
                </select>
```

So, Now what I want to do is that, In the child when user changes:

```
onChange={props.onChange}
```

this gets called in parent element, so here I also want to pass one more parameter with this like:

```
onChange = {props.onChange, props.id}so that Parent will get one Id as well, But its not working . And also I tried with the `props.onChange(props.id)` But no luck. Can any one help me with this ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent `onchange` function will receive `id` in 2nd argument.

```
onchange(event, id) {
    console.log("function will be callled", event.target.value, id);
}
```

While calling from child you call like this.

```
onChange={(e)=> {props.onChange(e, props.id)}}
```

Comment: It is giving an udefined value. Do I need to change something in the parent as well  in bind(this, id) ?

Comment: I got this one.

Comment: its should be `props.key` instead of `props.id` rt?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are not recommended to bind a function directly in render. Because when you bind a function directly in render your component will render for many reasons like setState, when new props received etc. so every time it renders it will create a new function in webpack generated bundle file so the file size becomes large. so always do binding in constructor

Now regarding your issue. Do map in render directly and pass `onChange` as a prop down to LowRow component. You need to do something like below to pass a function as a prop and send params to it in child component and access it in parent component. This concept is called callbacks in react.

One more thing never forget to add a key to parent jsx element whenever you generate jsx elements in loop. The key should be a unique id from data. If your data don't conatin unique id then pass index as key like **key={"key" +index}**

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange(event, id) {
    console.log("test", event, id);
 }

render(){
   const { lowData } = this.props;
   return(
     <div>
        {this.props.lowData && this.props.lowData.Low.map(data => (
             <LowRow key={data.id} technologies={this.state.technologies} onChange={this.onChange} data={data} key={data.id} />
         ))}
     </div>
   )
}
```

Select onChange

Here not sure what id are you passing. but you can pass params like how I did in the below code

```
<select className="selectpicker btn btn-labeled btn-start selectId techDrop  margin-left-10" onChange={e  => props.onChange(e, id)}>
                    <option disabled selected value>None Selected</option>
                    {props.technologies && <Select techData={props.technologies} options={props.technologyName} />}
                </select>
```

Comment: But Here, WHen I am passing another function through props and then that function I am calling on click of the plus button then its not getting called

Comment: Are you passing the function as I INSTRUCTED IN MY ANSWER?

Comment: NP. Kindly do upvote and accept if my solution helped.